# transformers longformer classification problem with f1, precision and recall classification

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am replicating code from this [page](https://github.com/jlealtru/website_tutorials/blob/main/notebooks/Longformer%20with%20IMDB.ipynb) and I am getting F1, precision and recall to be 0. I got accuracy as shown by the author. What could be reason?

I looked into `compute_metrics` function and it seems to be correct. I tried some toy data as below and `precision_recall_fscore_support` seems to be giving a correct answer

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support

y_pred = [1, 1, 2]
y_true = [1, 2, 2]
print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))

precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='binary')


0.6666666666666666
(0.5, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, None)
```

as I am getting the accuracy it seems that the below part is working as expected

```
labels = pred.label_ids
preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)

acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
```

Comment: DerekG made a very useful point in stating that 'pos_label' or the '[0,1] convention' should be used, but I dont see that explaining how recall, precision and F1-Score is 0.. did OP make any progress?

Comment: I will udpate soon..thanks to both of you

Comment: @Artur concretely if the formatting of the labels in the poster's problem is such that no labels are assigned the numerical value `1`, then F1, precision and recall will all be 0 as `1` is  the only label that affects these metrics by default. This reason also fully explains the phenomenon in the code posted. If this is not sufficient to explain the results on the poster's actual data they should post enough of such data to illustrate the remaining discrepancy

Comment: @Artur was correct and I rewarded him with a bounty, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the transformation of your dependend variable was somehow messed up.
This I think because all your metrics which depend on TP (True Posivites) are 0 ->

Both **Precision** and **Sensitivity**(Recall) depend on TP as numerator:

```
Precision = TP / (TP + FP)
Sensitivity = TP / (TP + FN)
```

**F1-Score** depends on both metrics and therefore on TP as numerator:

```
F1-Score = 2(Precision*Sensitivity)/(Precision+Sensitivity)
         = TP / (TP + 1/2(FN+FP))
```

->If the numerator is 0 because you have no TP the result will be 0 as well!

A good/moderate Accuracy can also be achieved if you only got the TN right:

```
Accuracy = (TP + TN) / Total
```

That is why you can have a valid looking accuracy and 0 for the other metrics.

So peek into your test/training sets and look whether the split was succesful and whether **both possible outcomes of you binary variable** are available in both sets! If one of them is lacking in the training set, this might explain a complete missclassification and lack of TP in the test-set.

Answer (score 1):

One paragraph of explanatory color, skip to paragraph 2 for answer: precision, recall, F1 are binary metrics, i.e. they are meaningful for binary classification problems, but more specifically they are useful when you want to predict the presence or absence of a single attribute. A typical problem in which such metrics might be useful would be classifying patient data as cancerous (positive) or non-cancerous (negative). In this case, precision is meaningful (how many of the examples that you predict have cancer actually have cancer?) and recall is meaningful (of the cancerous examples, what proportion do you catch?). Precision / recall are less useful for a binary or multiclass classification problem between two categorical classes of equal importance (say, red and green). It is less useful to give precision in this case because precision is in reference to a specific label. For instance, depending on how you calculate it, precision may mean (proportion of examples I said were red, that actually were red) or (proportion of examples I said were green, that actually were green). It is unclear which of these labels should be viewed as the primary label, so the metric is less useful in this case.

All this is a roundabout way of saying, precision and recall as implemented in `sklearn` by default expect to work with a single binary attribute. **The convention for such binary classification problems is to use 0 for the negative attribute label, and 1 for the positive attribute label.** The functions by default expect this.

Thus, your use of `[1,2]` rather than `[0,1]`labels in a binary classification problem is misleading and the functions are making a different calculation than you expect. As a trivial example:

```
  from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support

  y_pred = [0, 0, 1]
  y_true = [0, 1, 1]
  print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))

  precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='binary')

  # Result
  >>> 0.6666666666666666
  >>> (1.0, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666, None)
  
  # Using your original labels 

  y_pred = [1, 1, 2]
  y_true = [1, 2, 2]
  print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))

  precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='binary')

  # Result
  >>> 0.6666666666666666
  >>> (0.5, 1, 0.6666666666666666, None)
```

While you can change the "positive" label index within the function using `pos_label` argument, it is better practice to use `[0,1]` labels for your problem if for no other reason than convention / the vast majority of libraries are implemented with this representation assumed.