# Weird results in the test of Token Classification model - CamemBERT

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition

I am working on a NER task using the [camembert-base](https://huggingface.co/camembert-base) model and Pytorch for the fine-tuning, the obtained model is not giving good results for now but at least the labels of some sentences from the training corpus are predicted correctly.

The training is done using this [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Odq6eTexLg9ZXCjbWbnZiWMGAqg9Ut45/view?usp=sharing), more details can be found in this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I7cFPaQNWjV_jT3_FJ9LtcxEfAwNO5a3?usp=sharing).

The weird thing about this model is that in the test phase, some labels got a null precision, recall, and f1 score! This is pretty weird as it I think it means that the model didn’t manage to predict any entities for that label, a thing that I think is not possible as a model doing random shots can predict at least one label correctly.
I tried to test the model on the training data, and got the following results, I don't understand why this is happening with data that the model has already seen.

```
{'age': {'f1': 0.9339622641509434,
         'number': 420,
         'precision': 0.9252336448598131,
         'recall': 0.9428571428571428},
 'anatomie': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 1070, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'date': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 38, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'dose': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 102, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'duree': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 105, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'examen': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 721, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'frequence': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 77, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'genre': {'f1': 0.5926748057713652,
           'number': 426,
           'precision': 0.5621052631578948,
           'recall': 0.6267605633802817},
 'issue': {'f1': 0.18621973929236502,
           'number': 285,
           'precision': 0.1984126984126984,
           'recall': 0.17543859649122806},
 'mode': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 77, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'moment': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 174, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'origine': {'f1': 0.49336283185840707,
             'number': 426,
             'precision': 0.4665271966527197,
             'recall': 0.5234741784037559},
 'overall_accuracy': 0.8862863686790967,
 'overall_f1': 0.21902729417050434,
 'overall_precision': 0.37072243346007605,
 'overall_recall': 0.15542802486848398,
 'pathologie': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 211, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'sosy': {'f1': 0.03614457831325302,
          'number': 1161,
          'precision': 0.03911735205616851,
          'recall': 0.03359173126614987},
 'substance': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 371, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'traitement': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 254, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0},
 'valeur': {'f1': 0.0, 'number': 355, 'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0}}
```

Any clues to fix this issue, is it possible that this problem comes from the frequency of the labels used in the dataset? or could it be something else? And what can I do to fix?

Comment: For future reference, SO best practice is to post enough code that a reader can attempt to solve your problem without visiting links to other sites, notebooks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is from the testing portion of **your notebook**:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seqeval/metrics/v1.py:57: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086923/transformers-longformer-classification-problem-with-f1-precision-and-recall-cla/71133646#71133646) recent similar SE post as to why this results in unstable F1, precision, and recall scores. Long story short, these metrics rely on there being true positives and predicted positves for these labels in your data partition, so without such positives the metrics are ill-defined.

Comment: I tried to add the zero-division and removed the warning, what I don't understand is how such a performance is possible with tests made on the training data, a data that the model has seen before!

Answer (score 0):

It's not apparent from the content of your question, but when doing the NER didn't you use one-letter labels?

I got a similar problem when using Seqeval pakcage to compute metrics. It turned out that when I used mono-character labels like 'U' or '0' for NER, the `seqeval/metrics/sequence_labeling.py` script truncates a letter during processing, so the labels taken for comparison are empty.

Changing the labels to 'UU' and '00' solved the problem.