# Fine-tuning Token Classification with custom entities: “UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined”

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-datasets

I’m attempting to fine-tune `distilbert-base-uncased` model for token classification with custom entities. The [dataset](https://github.com/zliucr/CrossNER/tree/main/ner_data/ai) has the annotated tags in IOB-format.

I imported and created a huggingface DatasetDict following the documentation. Each dataset Features is defined as below:

```
Features({
'id': Value(dtype='int32', id=None),
'tokens': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='string', id=None), id=None),
'ner_tags': Sequence(feature=ClassLabel(num_classes=ner_tags_num_classes, 
names=ner_tags_names, id=None), id=None)
})
```

And ner tags mapping is the following:

```
{0: 'O', 1: 'B-product', 2: 'I-product', 3: 'B-field', 4: 'I-field', 
5: 'B-task', 6: 'I-task', 7: 'B-researcher', 8: 'I-researcher', 9: 'B-university', 
10: 'B-programlang', 11: 'B-algorithm', 12: 'I-algorithm', 13: 'B-misc', 14: 'I-misc', 
15: 'I-university', 16: 'B-metrics', 17: 'B-organisation', 18: 'I-organisation', 19: 'I-metrics', 
20: 'B-conference', 21: 'I-conference', 22: 'B-country', 23: 'I-programlang', 24: 'B-location', 
25: 'B-person', 26: 'I-person', 27: 'I-country', 28: 'I-location'}
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/2?fw=tf#metrics) for every step.
However, when it comes to compute the metric by using seqeval on the test set, this is the output that I get:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seqeval/metrics/v1.py:57: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 
Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
{'algorithm': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 191},
 'conference': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 391},
 'country': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 57},
 'field': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 93},
 'location': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 412},
 'metrics': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 521},
 'misc': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 181},
 'organisation': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 67},
 'person': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 219},
 'product': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 177},
 'programlang': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 201},
 'researcher': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 207},
 'task': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 44},
 'university': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1': 0.0, 'number': 183},
 'overall_precision': 0.0,
 'overall_recall': 0.0,
 'overall_f1': 0.0,
 'overall_accuracy': 0.6539285236246821}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem.

- Is the model performing so bad that I get ill-defined precision and f-score?
- Did I commit some error when I created the dataset?
- Do I have to look at the fine-tuning part of the code or only the evaluation part?
- Is there another way to evaluate the model using a test set which is a tensorflow dataset?

Comment: I had a similar problem when I used single letter labels, but I don't think this is your case. I wrote more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158579/weird-results-in-the-test-of-token-classification-model-camembert/71165767#answer-78041913